# understanding onOptionsItemSelected

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have 2 activities with action bar which has this code in its `onCrate` method:

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

And here is the `onOptionsItemSelected`:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
   switch (item.getItemId()) 
   {
     case android.R.id.icon:
        finish();
        return true;
     default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
   }
}
```

The first activity has a parent activity (configured in the manifest) the second one just opened from fragment (without parent fragment configured in the manifest). In the first activity, when I click the icon, the activity `item.getItemId()` value is the same as `android.R.id.icon` which then falls in the switch statement (case: `Android.R.id.icon`). In the second activity those values are deferent. Why this is happening? I would like to fall in the case: `Android.R.id.icon` in both activities.

Comment: Can you post the class signature of both first and second activity ?

Comment: @blackbelt what part of it would be helpful? this classes has lots of code in them.

Comment: You need to use the item id from the `menu.xml` file for that to work. Don't access the ids via the R file.

Comment: only the signature. I read your post tree times and I have not understood if the class is a fragment or an activity

Comment: Both classes are activities (the second activity opened from fragment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `android.R.id.icon` use `android.R.id.home`

Try this code:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
    case android.R.id.home:
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

For more detail check [this link](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use this type of code

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        menu.add(1, 1, 1, "Done").setIcon(R.drawable.img_done)
                .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
        menu.add(1, 2, 2, "Save").setIcon(R.drawable.img_save)
                .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
        return true;
    }




public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case 1:
        // Write your code for the first button
        break;
    case 2:
          // Write your code for the second button
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
    {
       switch (item.getItemId()) 
       {
         case R.id.icon:            //where 'icon' would be your item ID from menu.xml.
            finish();
            return true;
         default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using `android.R.id.icon` that might be wrong. Instead of that you may want to use `R.id.icon`.
There is a difference between both **`R.id.icon`** and **`android.R.icon`** files.

Also make sure that you are not using following import

```
import android.R;
```

It may lead you to unwanted results.